# Upgrading MySQL 5.6 to MariaDB 10.5 on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop: Fatal error in defaults handling

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to upgrade MySQL 5.6 to MariaDB 10.5 on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

I have removed the MySQL per [directions](https://%20https://phoenixnap.com/kb/uninstall-mysql) (unlinking `/usr/local/mysql`).

I have installed MariaDB per [installation page](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=20.04%20%22focal%22&v=10.5).

It succeeded, reporting the following troubles:

```
Setting up mariadb-common (1:10.5.22+maria~ubu2004) ...
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback (part of link group my.cnf) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/my.cnf is dangling; it will be updated with best choice
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
```

...

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service → /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Attempting to run it results in the following error message:

```
$ mysql
mysql: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
$ mariadb
mariadb: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
$ mysqld
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
```

`systemctl status mariadb.service` returns the following output:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.22 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-09-07 17:44:36 IDT; 26min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
   Main PID: 185391 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.22 database server...
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 sh[185388]: [108B blob data]
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 sh[185388]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadbd[185391]: [100B blob data]
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadbd[185391]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.22 database server.
```

Here are the relevant lines from the output of `journalctl -xr`:

```
Sep 07 17:44:40 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 dbus-daemon[1096]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.1907' (uid=0 pid=186517 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedeskto" label="unconfi>
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service target mysql.server.service has different name
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.server.service is not a symlink, ignoring.
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.22 database server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--  
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
--  
-- The job identifier is 42629 and the job result is failed.
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--  
-- The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--  
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
--  
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadbd[185391]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadbd[185391]: [100B blob data]
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 sh[185388]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 sh[185388]: [108B blob data]
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.22 database server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--  
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
--  
-- The job identifier is 42629.
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service target mysql.server.service has different name
Sep 07 17:44:36 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.server.service is not a symlink, ignoring.
Sep 07 17:44:35 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 07 17:44:35 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service target mysql.server.service has different name
Sep 07 17:44:35 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.server.service is not a symlink, ignoring.
Sep 07 17:44:35 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 07 17:44:35 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service target mysql.server.service has different name
Sep 07 17:44:35 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.server.service is not a symlink, ignoring.
Sep 07 17:44:35 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1694097874.898:240): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" info="profile does not exist" error=-2 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mariadbd" pid=185287 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 audit[185287]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" info="profile does not exist" error=-2 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mariadbd" pid=185287 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: at https://mariadb.org/jira
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: the maria-discuss email list at https://launchpad.net/~maria-discuss
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: You can find the latest source at https://downloads.mariadb.org and
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: --general-log gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql that may be helpful.
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: Try '/usr/sbin/mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:     MariaDB> show tables;
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:     shell> /usr/bin/mariadb -u root mysql
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mariadb
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:     shell> /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --general-log &
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: You can also try to start the mariadbd daemon with:
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:     shell> /usr/bin/mariadb-install-db --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: my.cnf files. You can ignore these by doing:
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: The problem could be conflicting information in an external
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: /var/lib/mysql for more information.
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]:  
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: [98B blob data]
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 mariadb-server-10.5.postinst[185259]: [108B blob data]
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
-- Subject: A start job for unit motd-news.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--  
-- A start job for unit motd-news.service has finished successfully.
--  
-- The job identifier is 42317.
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--  
-- The unit motd-news.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
-- Subject: A start job for unit motd-news.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--  
-- A start job for unit motd-news.service has begun execution.
--  
-- The job identifier is 42317.
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service target mysql.server.service has different name
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Wants dependency dropin /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.server.service is not a symlink, ignoring.
Sep 07 17:44:34 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 07 17:40:50 b-IdeaPad-L3-15IML05 dbus-daemon[1096]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
```

Here are a few more things I have tried:

```
$mariadb-upgrade
mariadb-upgrade: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
$ mysqld --print-defaults
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
$ my_print_defaults --mysqld
my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I would recommend against installing a database on top of your main OS. Install it in a vm (free virtualbox), or in a docker container. It's much simpler to upgrade/downgrade, and to turn it on/off as needed. You can even have both (or more) [same/different] versions of the database running at the same time, as needed.

Comment: @TheImpaler I need it for a Wordpress installation that duplicates the live one.  Had no problem with MySQL.  I want something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fatal error in defaults handling" is an indication that in your configuration file there is an include to a difference configuration file that either doesn't exist, or has permission problems such that the MariaDB server cannot read the file.

To trace down which file, run:

```
sudo -u mysql mysqld --no-defaults --verbose --help | grep -A 1 'Default options'
```

There will be a list of files like:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` I expect there will be:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Your question said `/etc/mysql/conf.d` didn't exist.

For simplicity I'd remove `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/` from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and then the server should start.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  However, it does not work: you suggest to run `sudo -u mysql mysqld`.  It fails with the same error message as before, "mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted"

Comment: I have found /etc/mysql/my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf -> /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf which contained the line "!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/".  I commented it out and it worked!  Thanks!

Comment: Added `--no-defaults`, second edit is still possible.